Python/Pygame: How do you get an actor to move around randomly/drift to a position?
I can't get my actor to move around the screen randomly. I tried getting a random position to be generated and then slowly make it to drift diagonally or whichever way but I couldn't get this to work as it just disappeared and respawned in the position instead of drifting.  The reason I tried to already set the random position beforehand is so I can make sure it doesn't go out of bounds.  The game is where you have to move the spaceship (ufo) and dodge the asteroids that are moving around randomly across the screen.  There are three asteroids.  I have currently coded the ufo's movement, made the background and imported the asteroids.  Please keep in mind I'm quite new to pygame I don't want it to just respawn in the position but for it to actually drift
import pgzrun
import random
import time
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 500
TITLE = "Dodge The Asteroid"
ufo = Actor("spaceship")
ufo.pos = 0,0
asteroid1 = Actor("reasteroid")
asteroid2 = Actor("reasteroid")
asteroid3 = Actor("reasteroid")
asteroid1.pos = 100,100
asteroid2.pos = 200,200
asteroid3.pos = 300,300
def draw():
    screen.blit("starrybackground",(0,0))
    ufo.draw()
    asteroid1.draw()
    asteroid2.draw()
    asteroid3.draw()
#For the movement of the ufo
def update():
    if keyboard.right:
        ufo.x = ufo.x + 3
    if keyboard.left:
        ufo.x = ufo.x - 3
    if keyboard.down:
        ufo.y = ufo.y + 3
    if keyboard.up:
        ufo.y = ufo.y - 3

while True:
    asteroid1xaxis = random.randint(0,WIDTH)
    asteroid1yaxis = random.randint(0,HEIGHT)
    while asteroid1.pos != (asteroid1xaxis,asteroid1yaxis):
        asteroid1.x = asteroid1.x + 2
        asteroid1.x = asteroid1.x + 2
pgzrun.go()



Just make a variable for the asteroid X and Y, and in your loop constantly change it by a bit and then blit it onto a screen. In my opinion, your code is unnecessarily complicated. Also, you're only moving the X position. Was that intended?

I'm confused what do you mean by change it by a bit.  I tried that but what if it isn't moving perfectly diagonally.  Could I have some code and more detail please?

Just change it by like one or two each frame. Can't really help much further.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
